# Java GRPC ServerBuilder vs NettyServerBuilder

Tags: java, grpc

Can someone tell me what's the difference between ServerBuilder and NettyServerBuilder?
Description for latest

> A builder to help simplify the construction of a Netty-based GRPC server.

Both are serving http2/grpc. With both you can serve GRPC service.
Does it mean that second (Netty) has more control on the protocol/transport level then former?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServerBuilder` is an abstract class and not directly usable whereas `NettyServerBuilder` is a concrete class (instantiated using `forPort` or `forAddress`).

gRPC-java comes with various transport implementations (see [gRPC transport](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java#transport)) and Netty is the main transport implementation.

Comment: This is not correct. Although `ServerBuilder` is abstract, `ServerBuilder.forPort()` allows creating a concrete instance.

Answer (score 1):

`ServerBuilder` is a generic builder with a stable API. It is generally recommended.

`NettyServerBuilder` is specific to the Netty transport and has more advanced options. However, it is unstable API. Any Netty-specific methods may be changed at any time, although in practice it has been relatively stable as the gRPC developers realize it is in wide use. But breakages can come from other sources. For example, if gRPC upgraded from Netty 4 to Netty 5 (which doesn't exist yet, but is being worked on), gRPC might delete the entire `io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder` class and add a new `io.grpc.netty5.NettyServerBuilder` class. gRPC could even choose to drop Netty entirely and use SomeOtherNetworkingLibrary.

Libraries must never use unstable API, as they do not control the version of gRPC being used. Applications can use unstable APIs, but should be aware that the API is not guaranteed and they may need to pay added costs in the future to stay up-to-date.

Comment: Is there any way to set maxconnectionage and maxconnectionagegrace using ServerBuilder?

Comment: @Abhay, I don't think so today. Feel free to file a feature request on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java